# There are ways to bypass integer limits for smooth auto scrolling page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve a smooth auto-scrolling page using the scrollTop method, but it only allows me to go down 1px down every 70ms. I assumed that fractional numbers such as 0.9999 would be available to me for a more slippery effect, but I was wrong. if ways to move without jumping?

```
setInterval(() => {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
        $(window).scrollTop(0)
    } else {
        $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1)
    }
}, 70)
```

Comment: not sure if this would help, but there is a `scroll-behavior: smooth;` attribute that might help

Comment: I used window.scrollTo({ behavior: 'smooth' }), but it didn't work

Comment: so this doesn't scroll smoothly for you: `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`?

Comment: @Bertov You said, *", but it only allows me to go down 1px down every 70ms"*  If the duration is set for a transition (simple animation) is too short, it will appear choppy to the human eye. 70ms is too short, the average for an animated element is 500 - 1000ms. In addition, an easing would help to smooth a transition as well.

Comment: All this time I was testing a page on Mac on which the behavior properties: smooth were useless. Then I used the emulator, and to my surprise this property really works there. Strange that Safari for Mac it ignores

Comment: @zer00ne, you’re right, but for my application the speed of 500ms is incredibly high. I needed to be able to read the credits from a small-print mobile device, but with these rough moves, it’s disgusting